# How to replace null values on pivot table with python

Tags: python, null, sum, aggregate, zero

this is my code:

```
df.groupby(['AÑO', 'MARCA'])['CONTEO'].aggregate('sum').unstack()
```

when I am doing the pivot table I am getting null  values,
How can I replace null values over the pivot table with O (zeros)??

Anyone has suggestions on that??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna`

```
df.fillna(0)
```